# How to subString a block of user generated HTML while preserving formatting?

Tags: c#, html, substring

I'd like to create the typical preview paragraph with a [read more] link. Problem is, the content that I'd like to SubString() contains text and html, written by a user with a WYSIWYG editor.

Of course, I check to make sure the string is not null or empty, then SubString() it, problem is that I could end up breaking the html tags, throwing off the rendering of the entire site.

The WYSIWYG editor doesn't seem to create perfectly formatted HTML, and many times seems to use `<br />` tags instead of `<p></p>`, etc... basically, I can't rely on well-formed tags, etc.

My workaround was to just strip out all HTML and substring the leftover text. This works, but loses any of the formatting that was in the HTML.

What's the best method of SubString()'ing a block of non-well-formed HTML while maintaining HTML that won't break the rendering of the site?

Comment: Think about letting through the stuff like '<h1>I am very visible</h1>' ? I think simple is beautiful and your current approach of stripping html altogether is reasonable.

Comment: Actually both <br /> and <p></p> are well-formed XML and HTML.

Comment: tsilb is correct.  Are you sure the HTML isn't well formed?

Comment: @tsilb & drs9222 - well, I've got way to guarantee that <p> will defintely be followed by </p>.

Comment: @ Andrew Y - brain fart... your right, I could just let some key tags through the regex. LOL! derp... ty

Comment: @Andrew Y again - write up an answer to that effect and I'll mark it as the answer. ;D

Comment: I was just about to ask the exact same question -- did you find a reasonable workaround for this? Nothing showing up on a Google search and I only found this while asking in StackOverflow itself. I can't believe this is not a more common problem? Maybe user generated WYSIWYG text is not yet that common?

Comment: There is this: https://www.quora.com/With-JavaScript-how-can-I-create-a-preview-of-user-generated-HTML-document-content which suggests using an iFrame.

Answer (score 0):

What about iterating through that substring searching for any not closed tags and saving these to a List, while removing any, which are closed? Then you could append the closing tags for any opened tags from the List (in reversed order), which would give you usable html...

Comment: That was my first thought when I saw this question, but a naive implementation would break on even common HTML atrocities. For example, <i><b></i></b> would only work by accident at best. You'd have to backtrack to the last matching opening tag in the list, output the appropriate closing tags along the way. With this addition, your approach would produce valid HTML, but it might not be the HTML the user expected. On the other hand, web browsers are complex beasts, and you'll never replicate their error "handing" quirks. Simple is good, but you may still want to code for common special cases.

Comment: If you use raw string length you have the issue of a potentially broken end tag (either an opening or a closing tag or even a combined one). If you use length of text inside elements (best choice) as the starting point you still have issues with not really knowing the size of the results. H1 test is going to take up much more room than P's etc. Problem is getting the text inside elements is impossible if the elements are stacked and run way past the preferred cut point. This seemly simple operations quickly escalates out of control...

Comment: Not to mention the mess that might ensue if a user cut and pasted the html/text in the first place :)